# Bootstrap spans, sidebar and @media

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an intuition that I'm doing something wrong. What is the "right" way to do this?

Currently, I have an `nav.span3` for navigation on the left side, and `section.span9` where content goes. However, in `@media print` I want to hide the `nav`. This pushes my content to the left, which is desired, and introducing a span3-sized gap at the right side, which is not.

I can't change `.span9` to `.span12` inside CSS `@screen print`; and defining my own class with dependent width (copied from Bootstrap's `.span9` and `.span12`) feels icky, as I feel as if I'm invading Bootstrap's space. So I'm kind of stumped what would be the best option.

How can I hide my `nav` and resize the content accordingly?

Comment: Have you tried the `.hidden-print` class?

Comment: @WindShear: No, because it only exists in Bootstrap Responsive, and it does exactly the same thing I'm doing myself (hiding the element by declaring its `display`). It does nothing for the size of the other elements. And while I understand that expecting responsiveness from an unresponsive version of the library might be foolish, I'd still like a solution. At worst, I will define my own conditional style as said in the main post, I just wanted to see if people had better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if this is a good solution (in your case) that I would overwrite the width of `.span9` to `100%` in the `style.css` file

Comment: Sorry, that's even ickier than defining my own class based on `.span9` and `.span12`.